# Tricky Regex with matching brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract variable names from a large block of text. The variables are identified by 2 opening and closing brackets [[varname]]. The problem is that some of the variables are references to an index in an array [[varname[0]]].

I've tried `\[{2}(.+?)\]{2,}`. The matched text for the array vars is correct, but the text in the captured group is missing the trailing bracket. For example, in the string:

```
"This is an array var [[arrayvar[0]]]"
```

I'm trying to match `[[arrayvar[0]]]` get out `arrayvar[0]` via the group.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do https://regex101.com/r/lH1zQ0/4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
\[\[(.*?(?:\[\d+\])?)\]\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/O4bu0M1h3aUtsHxr)

Comment: That matches the text, but the has some issues capturing the text contained between the brackets. I've updated the question to be more clear and I've included a better example.